# How to get custom font work in the recent expo update?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

*Update:
When running expo start, the fonts work,
When running as recommended npx expo start the fonts dont work, i even used google fonts using '@expo-google-fonts/montserrat'*

I have tried several ways to get fonts to show, works fine with JS but not on TSX in the following one,

```
if (!fontsLoaded) {
return null;
}
```

did not load the app, just a blank white screen,
when if (!fontsLoaded) {return null;} is removed, the following error appeares:

"fontFamily "Inter-Black" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync."

I have tried the one provided by expo.dev website, as well same issue and error.

I am using Expo SDK 49.0.13
Expo version 6.3.10
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.72.5

Currently the one I am using:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
    import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
    // import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
    import HomeNavigator from './src/routes/app.routes';


    export default function App() {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(["Sending..."]);
    useEffect(() => {}, []);
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Thin': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Thin.ttf'),
    'Light': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
    'ExtraLight': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf'),
    'Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    'Medium': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
    'Semibold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    'Black': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf')
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
      if (fontsLoaded) {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }, [fontsLoaded]);

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
    }
```

The one provided by expo:

```
    import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf'),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Inter Black</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/fonts/#use-fontloadasync-instead-of-the-usefonts-hook) will explain the error you are getting.

From my point of view, what I see is that you are trying import a font with the file extension of **.ttf** and in the docs use the new type of fonts **.otf**. Maybe the framework doesn't recognize that extension and he thinks he may need to go out to the internet to find the file.

Check out here the differences between ttf and otf [here](https://www.coreldraw.com/en/tips/otf-vs-ttf/#:%7E:text=designers%20and%20hobbyists.-,The%20difference%20between%20OTF%20and%20TTF,with%20multiple%20options%20to%20use.).
bye

Comment: Both of them are not working even the provided one in the link. The return Null part is actually returning a blank white screen. when i remove it,  i have the same error that its not system font